# reverse iterator error : no match for 'operator!=' in 'rcit != std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rend() with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator'

Tags: c++, iterator

CODE A:

```
vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator rcit;
vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator tit=v.rend();
for(rcit = v.rbegin(); rcit != tit; ++rcit)
cout << *rcit << " ";
```

CODE B:

```
vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator rcit;
for(rcit = v.rbegin(); rcit != v.rend(); ++rcit)
cout << *rcit << " ";
```

CODE A works fine but
why does CODE B throughs error :

DEV C++\vector_test.cpp **no match for 'operator!=' in 'rcit != std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rend() with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator'**.

This is  the program I was trying to write.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
template< typename T > void printVector( const vector< T > &v);

template< typename T > 
void printVector( const vector< T > &v)
{
             typename vector< T >::const_iterator cit;
             for(cit = v.begin(); cit != v.end(); ++cit)
             cout << *cit << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    vector< int > v;

    cout << "Initial size of the vector : " << v.size()
         << " and capacity : " << v.capacity() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            cout << "Enter number : ";
            cin >> number;
            v.push_back(number);
    }
    cout << "Now size of the vector : " << v.size()
         << "and capacity : " << v.capacity() << endl;

    cout << "output vector using iterator notation " << endl; 
    printVector(v);

    cout << "Reverse of output ";
    vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator rcit;
    for(rcit = v.rbegin(); v.rend() != rcit ; ++rcit)
    cout << *rcit << " ";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits< streamsize >::max(), '\n'); 
    cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post some more code... the code you've posted is not the problem...

Comment: your code compiles for me just fine with mingw on windows

Comment: hmm thanks, @Vusak It might be my DevC++ compiler...hmm

Comment: @munish Yes, I have just stumbled into the same error using DevC++. Thanks to you question here, I found a workaround in no time!

Comment: This is reproducible with the Android NDK compiler revision 9 (and probably earlier versions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is there are two forms of the `rend` method:

```
reverse_iterator rend();
const_reverse_iterator rend() const;
```

When doing the comparison it seems the first is being used (though I don't know why), and the operator `!=` for comparing a 'const' and a 'non-const' iterator is not defined. When assigning to the variable though, the compiler can deduce the correct function to call and it all works correctly.

Comment: P.S. Your program runs fine for me compiling with gcc on Linux.

Comment: Thanks,sje397 this makes more sure that the fault can be with my compiler DevC++ 4.9.9.2. I dont know much about compilers I got it online and started using it.I dont know which compiler is suitable to learn and practice C++.Can you suggest some.

Comment: I'd suggest the Visual Studio compiler on Windows (there's a free 'express' edition) and gcc elsewhere - I've hardly touched anything else.

Comment: @sj397,Your explanation above seems O.K I guess because if I just use the non-const version of the iterator it compiles O.k , The problem occurs only when const_reverse_iterator is used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get any errors or warnings when I compile the following in Xcode 4 or codepad:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    using namespace std;
    vector< int > v;

    vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator rcit;
    for(rcit = v.rbegin(); rcit != v.rend(); ++rcit)
        cout << *rcit << " ";
}
```

Does your program differ from this in any significant way? What compiler are you using? Does ognian's suggestion work? And what if you replace the `!=` with an `==`? (I know it would cause a run-time error but I curious about the compiler's response to this.)

Comment: Note: Your full program listing compiles fine also.

Comment: No @ognian's  suggestion did not work.and I just  copied your code and pasted and ran.gives the same error,perhaps its my DevC++ compiler version 4.9.9.2.I did not try == though.@Vusak also compiled my code and it was fine

Comment: Thanks, yes it does as almost everybody above and below did it.Its the compiler .I need to test it elsewhere

Comment: It looks like DevC++ uses MinGW. I'm surprised you're getting this problem. For alternatives, a quick and fuss-free way to play around with C++ is with an online environment like [codepad](http://codepad.org/). And on Windows, Visual Studio Express 2010 is an IDE that I would highly recommend.

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping the operands of != like this:

```
for(rcit = v.rbegin(); v.rend() != rcit; ++rcit)
```

Comment: @Nawaz: on some crappy STL implementations it does